# Chosen with width equal to the largest option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to make the DropDownList with the JQuery-Chosen in it reacts like all others "normal" DropDownLists, matching the width equal to the largest option on the DDL.
I tried some different approaches to get this done, using css and JQuery, but all I tried became ugly.

At the official page of Chosen, http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html , it says:

> The width of the Chosen select box. By default, Chosen attempts to match the width of the select box you are replacing. If your select is hidden when Chosen is instantiated, you must specify a width or the select will show up with a width of 0.

Any way to workaround this?

Workspace: http://jsfiddle.net/cdtn0ko7/

```
$('.chosen').chosen({
    width: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: I removed `{width: 'auto'}` and it worked. If that's what you're going for that is. **Edit** never mind it consumes the entire width of the area.

Comment: Small fix, now loading the bootstrap-chosen: http://jsfiddle.net/5yL5qy8o/

Answer (score 4):

Try this out for size. :D

 **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdtn0ko7/2/)**

```js
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

```css
.form-control {
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I don't know if it's because I'm using ASP.NET, but this didn't work out for me. =(

What's happening with me right now: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/04/01/551c5474d348d.png

Comment: @Luisao If the DDL can't expand any further to the right it won't. I can't tell if there's more room to the right or not.
Also asp.net does like to mess with formatting. I use it at work a lot w/Bootstrap.

Comment: I just linked the SS to show that what u suggest worked on the JSFiddle but didn't work in my workspace(which I'm using asp.net). I'm also using Bootstrap, and the css on it is the bootstrap-chosen. There is enough room for the DDL, and it matched the width with the first option that I chose.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got the question right, but since you are using Bootstrap, you can just do something like this on the css:

```
.chosen-drop {
  position: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this following code and it worked, check this out:

```
$('.chosen').chosen({
    width: '100%'
});
```